# JSP/Servlets: How do I Upload a zip file, unzip it and extract the CSV file

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, csv, zip

Wondering how can I do the following in JSP/Servlets:

1. Upload a zip file (containing multiple CSV files)
2. Unzip the file to obtian the CSV files
3. Read the CSV files and pump the records into a mySQL database

Note: mySQL table is set up and ready for CSV files inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1: Upload a zip file (containing multiple CSV files)

Use a `multipart/form-data` form with `input type="file"` in HTML/JSP to be able to select a file and upload it. Use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) in the Servlet to be able to parse the request body and obtain the uploaded files. See also: [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

> 2: Unzip the file to obtian the CSV files

Use [`java.util.ZipInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) to read a zip file and extract the zip entries. See also: [Compressing and Decompressing files in Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html).

> 3: Read the CSV files and pump the records into a mySQL database

Two ways:

1. Put the CSV somewhere on the local disk file system where the MySQL has access to and instruct it to import it using a [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) query.
2. Use an existing [CSV parser](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+csv+parser) or [create one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225108/issues-converting-csv-to-xls-in-java-only-core-java-experience-needed-question/3225146#3225146) to parse a CSV into a useable collection of Java objects, e.g. `List<List<String>>`. Then [learn JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) and use [`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to create, populate and execute an `INSERT` query in batches. See also this [mini tutorial on MySQL and JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358).