# Upload a zip file, unzip and read file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, csv

i am using NetBeans, and i am working on a jsp page that allows the upload of a zip file. The zip file contains 6 CSV files, that is to be written to the SQL database.

My question is, how do i go about allowing the user to upload the file, unzip it in the jsp page, and allow me to read the file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, you're the third user in two days who asks **exactly** the same. Homework? Classmates? Colleagues? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771903/how-do-i-bootstrap-a-zip-file-to-jsbc-database-using-jsp-and-servlets and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768104/jsp-servlets-how-do-i-upload-a-zip-file-unzip-it-and-extract-the-csv-file

Comment: @BalusC hahaha, nice observation :)

Comment: hey thanks nice people of stackoverflow, i have found the answer. yes, it's a project, and fortunately the information i needed were hidden somewhere in the slides.

some useful link
http://www.javazoom.net/jzservlets/uploadbean/uploadbean.html, http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ and http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add an `<input type="file">` and make your `form` have `enctype="miltipart/form-data"`
2. Use [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) to obtain the `byte[]` of the file (in a servlet of yours)
3. Use [`java.util.zip.*`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) to extract the files. [See here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/)
4. Either parse the CVS ([here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/)) or if your database has an utility to import CSV, pass the files using `Runtime.exec(..)`

Comment: @Melvin - if an answer works for you, you can mark it as accepted (tick below the vote counter)