# REST - Unzipping a file from REST Call

Tags: java, collections

Say I get a list of file objects from a REST call

```
List<FileItem> zipFileList = processRequest(request);
```

where request is a HttpServletRequest

I want to unzip each file and write its unzipped contents to disk. Is this possible on the fly or do I first have to save the file to disk, and then unzip it? Thanks!

Comment: this queston has really nothing to do with rest. Remove the tag, please.

Comment: Very Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768104/jsp-servlets-how-do-i-upload-a-zip-file-unzip-it-and-extract-the-csv-file?rq=1

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code! What do you struggle with? What does the FileItem javadoc say on how to use it?